# I can not start Appium with Xiaomi Redmi 4x

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to run the application installed on my phone through appium to get the id of the necessary elements on the screen. These are my desired capabilities:[image]

When I try to start session I get the following error:[image]

Here is my appium log

```
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Keksimus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 16996ace7cf4 shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock'
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1566812265990 (12:37:45 GMT+0300 (Финляндия (лето)))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\Keksimus\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 16996ace7cf4 shell pm install -g /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/728413456b86856a2003edeb524d6bd577ca6418.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'Error: java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag'; Code: '1'
[MJSONWP] Error: Command 'C\:\\Users\\Keksimus\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 16996ace7cf4 shell pm install -g /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/728413456b86856a2003edeb524d6bd577ca6418.apk' exited with code 1
[MJSONWP]     at ChildProcess.proc.on.code (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\teen_process\lib\exec.js:94:19)
[MJSONWP]     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
[MJSONWP]     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
[MJSONWP]     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
[MJSONWP]     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
[MJSONWP]     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:596:12)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 5494 ms - 619
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 4 ms - 57
[HTTP]
```

I rummaged through a bunch of pages on the Internet, tried to update sdk to the latest version, tried to downgrade platform-tools to 28 but nothing solves the problem. What is your opinion?

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode on the phone ?

Comment: @BrianO'Neill Yes. I tried run new session with 100% right capabilities
{
  "deviceName": "Redmi",
  "appPackage": "com.miui.calculator",
  "appActivity": "com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "7.1.2"
} And still have this error

Comment: Ok. USB Debugging is enabled ? (Settings -> Developer Options -> Debugging -> USB debugging). Also, what happens when you execute 'adb devices'. Does your device show up ?

Comment: Copy/paste the output of your 'adb devices' command.

Comment: @BrianO'Neill Thank you very much. I had "USB debugging" turned on but "USB debugging (security settings)" was not turned on. This are 2 different points

Comment: btw if its important adb devices output is 
List of devices attached
16396ace7xf4    device

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with Xiaomi Redmi 4x. After enabled the USB debugging options and turn off the security options in Settings you can try following option.

Depending on [Appium documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/), adding `autoGrantPermissions` to your capabilities with `noReset` capability like following will work:

```
autoGrantPermissions : true
noReset : true
```